# Inequality of exponentials of Banach operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, matrix-exponential

(I have moved this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4068106/inequality-of-banach-operators) from Stackexchange).

Given the operators $\{A_j\}$ in a Banach algebra and a positive integer $p$, let
\begin{equation}
g=\exp\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^p A_j\right)\quad\text{and}\quad h=e^{A_1 / n}\dots e^{A_p / n}.
\end{equation}
Then prove that
\begin{align}
||g-h||&\leq||h||\cdot||gh^{-1} -1||\\
&\leq||h||\left\{\exp\left(\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j=1}^p ||A_j || \right)-\left(1+\frac{2}{n}\sum_{j=1}^p ||A_j ||\right)\right\}.
\end{align}

This is taken from the proof of Theorem $3$ from this [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01609348), but I cannot see how to get  to the second line of the equation above.

Comment: The link of the paper is not free!

Comment: So here is the paper for those who cannot access it: https://www.dropbox.com/s/jv3de625i6nys87/Suzuki_%20Generalized%20Trotter%27s%20Formula%20and%20Systematic%20Approximants%20of%20Exponential%20Operators%20and%20Inner%20Derivations%20with%20Applications%20to%20Many-Body%20Problems.pdf?dl=0